# Attach an external list with a sharepoint list by a common field

Tags: list, join, sharepoint-2010, external

I have a database (SQLSERVER) with a table (I have create an external list in SahrePoint):

> IDStore : int
>
> AdresseStore : text

And I have a SharePoint list with fields:

> ID : int
>
> NameStore : text
>
> IDStode : int

I want have a view with :

> IDStore
>
> NameStore
>
> AdresseStore

I can't use Visual studio I must use SharePoint Designer. Is It possible ?
I create a linked data source with a join between my two source but when i use this in a data view I can't see My two liste linked. the join isn't made ?
then my two lists have the field "IDStore" common.

how i can do ?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe SharePoint 2007-2013 supports joining external lists to SharePoint lists.